# Python Help - ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyheif

Tags: python, pyheif

I cannot install pyheif even after I've tried everything that I know. I'm running on Windows 11 with Pycharm Community 2023. I've reinstalled all of the software and restarted the system. I've tried to run different environments and interpreters but still not having any success. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Collecting pyheif
  Using cached pyheif-0.7.1.tar.gz (22 kB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
  Installing backend dependencies: started
  Installing backend dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
Collecting cffi>=1.0.0 (from pyheif)
  Using cached cffi-1.16.0-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (1.5 kB)
Collecting pycparser (from cffi>=1.0.0->pyheif)
  Using cached pycparser-2.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl (118 kB)
Using cached cffi-1.16.0-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl (181 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: pyheif
  Building wheel for pyheif (pyproject.toml): started
  Building wheel for pyheif (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
Failed to build pyheif

  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  Building wheel for pyheif (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  [25 lines of output]
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pyheif
  copying pyheif\constants.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pyheif
  copying pyheif\error.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pyheif
  copying pyheif\reader.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pyheif
  copying pyheif\writer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pyheif
  copying pyheif\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pyheif
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pyheif\data
  copying pyheif\data\version.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pyheif\data
  running build_ext
  generating cffi module 'build\\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\\Release\\_libheif_cffi.c'
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release
  building '_libheif_cffi' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\build
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/opt/local/include -IC:\Users\jerem\PycharmProjects\Scratch\.venv\include -IC:\Users\jerem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include -IC:\Users\jerem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /Tcbuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\_libheif_cffi.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\_libheif_cffi.obj
  _libheif_cffi.c
  build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\_libheif_cffi.c(570): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libheif/heif.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.38.33130\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyheif
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyheif, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently windows does not work with this library..... If I'm wrong then I will stand corrected.